# Why do some speakers pronounce the aɪ sound as ɔɪ?

Tags: pronunciation, accent, british-english

Essentially, I'm referring to how some British English speakers pronounce words like "time", "right". That first vowel changes and ends up sounding like "toyme" or "royght". Americans seem to have picked up on it, often laughing at us pronouncing "license" as "loicense", so it's definitely a real phenomenon.

It's something I've noticed among a lot of people, but it seems to be found somewhat randomly geographically - everywhere from the Black Country to Essex, and also in people from parts of the North. Is it a feature of some regional accents, or is it a class/age thing?

Comment: The OED gives the same IPA representation in BrE and AmE for ***void*** *(**/vɔɪd/**)*, but for ***lie*** they have BrE ***/lʌɪ/*** and AmE ***/laɪ/*** (the first vowel within the diphthong is more "open" in AmE). But although it's stereoptypically identified as "dialectal, uneducated, rustic", I think people who don't *actually* use the more "closed" initial vowel there *(**loy, toyme, royght**)* tend to massively exaggerate the difference when poking fun at people who don't speak *exactly* the way they do. Maybe it's a hangover from "The Great Vowel Shift", I dunno.

Comment: (Actually, ***All royght*** is quintessentially a ***West Country*** form of ***All right***. Northerners in the UK tend to veer more towards something like ***All rate*** - or ***All reet*** as you get up towards Scotland.)

Comment: I'll note that this pronunciation is likely popular in TV shows and the like because it's easy for an actor to mimic, even if it's not their native accent.

Comment: I don’t about those two diphthongs in particular, but I know one of those diphthongs, /ɔɪ/, in ([loin](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diphthong) = lɔɪn) is pronounced as /oɪ/ in an Australian accent but as /ɔɪ/ in Br RP accent.

Comment: In Derby I hear 'all raaaaht'

Comment: It's a well-known feature of the West Midlands accent (Derby being East Midlands!). In the 1960s a girl called Janice Nicholls became famous for saying "Oi'll give it foive" on a TV show where teenagers voted on pop singles - [see this link](https://nostalgiacentral.com/music/music-on-film-and-tv/thank-your-lucky-stars/)

Answer (score 2):

[As described in Geoff Lindsey's *Beyond RP,*](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-030-04357-5_13) this marks a difference between Received Pronunciation and the more modern Standard Southern British. In RP, the /aɪ/ diphthong is typically realized as [aɪ], similar to a common realization of it in General American (ignoring our version of [Canadian raising](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canadian_raising)). In SSB, by contrast, it is much further back, closer to [ɑɪ] or [ʌɪ], making it closer to a common General American realization of /ɔɪ/. This seems to be a recent phenomenon, so it is unsurprising that it would be slowly spreading through other British dialects.

Comment: It seems to be slightly different in lots of documents. For instance in [Cockney](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cockney) /aɪ/ has various realisations, generally further back, [ɑɪ], [ɒɪ] or even [ɑː].